# Wordpress - wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. Unsupported value type (array)

Tags: php, wordpress

I've run into an issue with wpdb::prepare on an older Wordpress website.

According to the debug.log, the issue started on Sept.20, 2017. When WP 4.8.2 was released.

The error is triggered as follows when a user logs in:

> PHP Notice:  wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. Unsupported value
>   type (array). Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information.
>   (This message was added in version 4.8.2.) in
>   /home/domain/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3416
>
> PHP Notice:  wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query does not
>   contain the correct number of placeholders (375) for the number of
>   arguments passed (2). Please see Debugging in WordPress for more
>   information. (This message was added in version 4.8.3.) in
>   /home/domain/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3416
>
> PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be
>   string, array given in /home/domain/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php
>   on line 1083

My issue is trying to find the source and what changes need to be made to fix it. Any suggestions of where to start or what would have changed in that WP fix. the changelog doesn't tell much.

Comment: You might want to start by looking at functions.php on line 3416

Comment: I would also search your theme and plugin code for any `wpdb->prepare` calls and check them against the spec to make sure the parameters are right

Comment: I really do wish $wpdb would log a bit more information about the object or data.